# How to create a link for password reset link by sending mail to user in java

Tags: java

```
 String messageValue[] = {userNameFull, programName, url, url, newPass, programSupportEmail, programSupportEmail, programSupportPhone, signature, programWebsite};

            //String subject = MessageUtil.getMessage("mail.ResetPasswordSubject", locale);
            //String message = MessageUtil.getDynamicMessage("mail.UserMailForgotPassword", messageValue, locale);;
            //mail.ResetPasswordSubject = Password Reset Request
            String subject = "Password Reset Request";
            String message = "Dear {0}"
                    + ",<br/>"
                    + "Greetings from the {1} Team."
                    + "<br/><br/>"
                    + "Your password has been reset."
                    + "<br/><br/>"
                    + "To access your account, "
                    + "please click on the following link:<br/>"
                    + "<a href={2}>{3}</a>"
                    + "<br/>"
                    + "or copy the link and paste it in your browser&#39s address bar."
                    + "<br/><br/>"
                    + "Your temporarily reset password will expire in 7 days "
                    + "and you will be asked to change it on your first login."
                    + "<br/>Login to your account using the following details:"
                    //+ "<br/><br/>Password:{4}"
                    //+ "<br/><br/>Password:"+newPass+""
```

here i have to enter the link for reset password in place of this  "
Password:"+newPass+"" please help me

Comment: Check [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Comment: is there any body to help me in code level,thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to avoid brute force attack in security perspective.

1. Create 32 char alphanumeric string as sessionid which will be valid till 7days (in your case)
2. Create code 8/12 char conformation code
3. Put reset link with sessionid in query param and conf code in email.
4. When user clicks on link, get him to insert conf code on ui.
5. Validate session id and conf code
6. All are valid, then show him his username and ask for new password and confirm password.

Comment: @Sushreesmita, he gave you an answer on what to _try_, no one can help you with code if you don't have any.

Comment: Why the session Id? This makes it more complicated and just a bit more secure. The number of possibilities, 26^32 not counting specials, should be more than sufficient - there are roughly 1.9*10^45 combinations. And you have to match in the database anyway.

Comment: with session-id, you can keep record of user activities in each session and its important for audit point of view